# Remove all of file type from tortoise svn repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've exceeded my svn hosting limit so I need to remove all binaries and images from it. How do I issue a command to delete and ignore for example all *.jpg files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply deleting the files now won't reclaim space. It will be marked as deleted, but the old revisions are still stored in the repository.

The only way to completely remove all traces of a file is to dump the repository (`svnadmin dump`), filter out the undesired files (use `svndumpfilter`), and create a new repository from the modified dump.

I would talk to your hosting service, since I would expect you don't have the required access to do this yourself.

Comment: Using "svnadmin dump" and "svnadmin load" is extremely dangerous. If you use it to get rid of selected revisions, and those revisions contain information about other non-binaries files, you will lose information and there is a chance that your new SVN repository won't be created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue, not having known what I shouldn't put in my svn repository before I started using it and have learned the hard way, to ignore the bin/obj directories and not include large files such as images etc that were never going to change much anyway.

I discovered [this blog post](http://publicmind.in/blog/dumping-a-remote-svn-repository-without-admin-access/) today which shows you how you can get a dump of your svn repository even if you don't have access to the machine where the respository is located.

I've been using TortoiseSVN up until now but to do the following from the command line I installed [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)

The steps are:

1. svnadmin create c:\localrepos
2. create a file called "pre-revprop-change.cmd" in c:\localrepos\hooks
3. svnsync init c:\localrepos https:\my.hosted.svn\repos
4. svnsync sync c:\localrepos
5. svnadmin dump c:\localrepos > localrepos.dmp

In my case this was sufficient to allow me to get a local copy of the hosted repository onto my machine with all the revision history intact so that I am now able to rethink what I really need my hosted repository to contain before I delete it and create a new one.  If you have a few people working on your project then I guess it's going to be more tricky.